# CPU Total is wrong displayed for a process in monit

Tags: freebsd, monit, mmonit

I am using Monit, and I am monitoring a few processes.

I have 12 vCPUS, and system is around 20% usage. Yet M/Monit shows some processes to go up to 100%. Well they actually do but just a single CPU.

How can I have M/Monit show CPU usage properly?
I am using "check process"

```
check process myprocess with matching myprocess
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux systems, 100% means 1 CPU core/thread used at 100% (or 2 CPU core/thread used at 50%, etc...)

If your system have 12 CPUs, you have an capacity of 1200%.

Monit will report percentage of consumption on term of core/thread and not full system capacity as the Operating system do.